# Conditional search returning tuples of arrays for 1D arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I read the documentation on [numpy's where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), and I don't understand why `where` would return a **tuple nesting an array** if I am checking a condition on a simple 1D array.

```
> import numpy as np
> my_array = np.random.randint(1,10, (20))
> np.where(my_array > 5)

(array([ 0,  1,  4,  6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18]),)
```

Why does `np.where` return a tuple in this case? Why nest the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's for consistency, consider a 2D array:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.random.randint(1,10, (4, 5))
pos = np.where(my_array > 5)
my_array[pos]
```

you can use the tuple as the index to select out all the values in the locations.